# Use DNS or similar to re-route URL shortener service when dedicated server is down

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, load-balancing, domain-name, dns-zone

I am trying to make a link shortener resilient to server failure by re-routing to a good server.

Example:

1. shortener.com/a1b2c3 > forwards to > website1.com

(shortener.com and website1.com are on different dedicated servers)

2. For argument's sake, lets say the http://shortener.com link is posted to Twitter. So the user journey is twitter.com > shortener.com > website1.com
3. Can I use DNS or some top layer infrastructure to detect shortener.com server is down and use alternative, to re-route traffic to website1.com?

[Link to show diagram of two scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBmHF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the DNS has no concept of systems being up or down. Aside from that, though, if a system like you seek *did* exist, how would it get its domain mapping information if the shortener itself is down.

With various public cloud providers, the ability to stand up a very highly-available web application like this is approaching trivial status. You should put your efforts into building a highly-available application.

Comment: Some valid points, although the most common cause of the server (cloud-based) being down is corrupt software, so even in a highly-available environment servers still go down.... What about dual-balancing? Or a gateway server before  shortener.com ?

Comment: Any of that requires your shortening data, which will need to be highly available anyway. Well-tested software combined with good alerting and the ability to quickly deploy fixes mitigates a lot of the chance of downtime. Additionally, putting extra layers of indirection in your application rarely does anything to increase stability. Rather, they introduce more SPOFs for you to manage.